# How do I contact the maintainers for apt-config-icons and variants?

Tags: apt

I have been having some hassles installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS under my Windows 10 Home WSL1 services, but I've narrowed down the culprit to apt-config-icons and its derivatives.

It took a couple days of install-break-wipe-repeat cycles to identify exactly what was breaking my WSL Ubuntu 20.04 apt cache, but I eventually narrowed it down.

If any of those packages get installed under WSL1, you can't update your apt cache any more.

How do I get this information to them?

Answer (score 2):

See the output of

```
apt-cache show apt-config-icons
```

That is

```
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Matthias Klumpp <mak@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
```